# Trying to set a analyzed state when a variable has finished analyzing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react project. I have made some changes to the way we render content to a screen and am now having a problem finding a solution.

I have a variable that returns text dependent on its content. If the variable is empty, which is its default state, we say that `no data was found`. If we have some data we render the data. The problem is, that I need to set a default value to the variable so it does not show `no data was found` when it is analyzing.

I have tried using state to set a analyzed flag but can't seem to get it to work?

So for example:

```
    let filterWhatToShowUser =
       // here we filter through the data and determine what the result of filterWhatToShowUser is shown to the user
    );
```

JSX

```
if there is data ?
<div>Show this</div> 
: 
<div>Show this when the object is empty</div> 
:
<div>Show this whilst the object is empty but evaluating</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data) => show data
if(!data && ! evaluating) show something
show something else
```

ternary operator is about "if & else", no need to make complex constructions out of them

Comment: That's great but how/ where do I set evaluating?

Comment: Set the flag at the beginning of the analysis and remove it at the end. Use state for this.

Comment: let filterWhatToShowUser = ()=> {
  setEvalueting(true)
  // code
  setEvalueting(false)
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).